# time series decomposition and multivariate models

Tags: r, time-series, multivariate-analysis, decomposition

I have a series of time series data which looks like:

```
# A tibble: 1,095 x 5
   date         ts1   ts2   ts3   ts4
   <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 2013-01-01    23    33    29    10
 2 2013-01-02    98   110   105    84
 3 2013-01-03    72   108    76    27
 4 2013-01-04   129   186   109    69
 5 2013-01-05   135   163   173   146
 6 2013-01-06   116   155   115    98
 7 2013-01-07    48    81    49    45
 8 2013-01-08    60    53    54    36
 9 2013-01-09    44    40    55    36
10 2013-01-10    51   101    82    48
# ... with 1,085 more rows
```

Lets say I want to predict `ts1` using the data from `ts2`, `ts3` and `ts4`. I could add in a number of time series features based on the date etc. weekday, weekend etc.

Say I use a model such as SVM, RandomForest etc. (the model is not important just that it can take in multivariate data and make a regression prediction).

What would be the best way for me to tackle this problem?

With the data I do the following:

```
library(lubridate)
library(forecast)
library(dplyr)

timeseriesdata <- ts_data %>% 
  mutate(
    day = day(date),
    month = month(date)           # create 
 # normal time series features based on the 
 # date
  ) %>% 
  as.ts(frequency = 365)
```

Which just creates some additional features and puts the data into time series (incorrectly, puts the data into time series)

```
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 6 
Frequency = 1 
   date ts1 ts2 ts3 ts4 day month
1 15706  23  33  29  10   1     1
2 15707  98 110 105  84   2     1
3 15708  72 108  76  27   3     1
4 15709 129 186 109  69   4     1
5 15710 135 163 173 146   5     1
6 15711 116 155 115  98   6     1
```

Next: The variables in the model are seasonal so I want to decompose them.

```
ts2_decomp <- msts(timeseriesdata[, 3], 
   seasonal.periods = c(7, 365)) %>% 
  tbats()

ts3_decomp <- msts(timeseriesdata[, 4], 
    seasonal.periods = c(7, 365)) %>% 
  tbats()
```

I can plot these:

```
plot(ts2_decomp)
plot(ts2_decomp)
```

In a standard decomposition model I can do something like `Y_t - S_t` to remove the seasonal component.

My question is, as part of the inputs to my "SVM/RandomForest" model what can I now add into the model, now that I have removed the seasonal, trend and cyclical components, or separated them?

That is, do I feed the model the `fitted.values`? or should I take the `S`, the `C` and the `T` decomposed values and feed these to the model as "new information/variables".

If this is "allowed" how can I access the `level`, `season1` and `season2` parts of the `tbats` decomposition?

I am just a little confused here since previously I was just applying (naively) past `ts2`, `ts3` and `ts4` (as well as past `ts1`) time series in order to try to predict future `ts1` levels.

I can add the fitted values back to the data to create my final data:

```
decomped_ts_features <- bind_cols(
  data.frame(
    ts2_fitted = ts2_decomp$fitted.values,
    ts3_fitted = ts3_decomp$fitted.values
  ),
  data.frame(timeseriesdata)
) %>% 
  as_tibble()

decomped_ts_features


# A tibble: 1,095 x 9
   ts2_fitted ts3_fitted  date   ts1   ts2   ts3   ts4   day month
        <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1       71.8       57.0 15706    23    33    29    10     1     1
 2       46.7       37.6 15707    98   110   105    84     2     1
 3       93.5       85.9 15708    72   108    76    27     3     1
 4       89.6       68.4 15709   129   186   109    69     4     1
 5       87.4       51.9 15710   135   163   173   146     5     1
 6       69.7       74.6 15711   116   155   115    98     6     1
 7      110.       118.  15712    48    81    49    45     7     1
 8       60.0       53.5 15713    60    53    54    36     8     1
 9       50.3       57.0 15714    44    40    55    36     9     1
10       43.8       61.1 15715    51   101    82    48    10     1
```

Any advice would be great.

Data:

```
        data <- structure(list(date = structure(c(16071, 16072, 16073, 16074, 
16075, 16076, 16077, 16078, 16079, 16080, 16081, 16082, 16083, 
16084, 16085, 16086, 16087, 16088, 16089, 16090, 16091, 16092, 
16093, 16094, 16095, 16096, 16097, 16098, 16099, 16100, 16101, 
16102, 16103, 16104, 16105, 16106, 16107, 16108, 16109, 16110, 
16111, 16112, 16113, 16114, 16115, 16116, 16117, 16118, 16119, 
16120, 16121, 16122, 16123, 16124, 16125, 16126, 16127, 16128, 
16129, 16130, 16131, 16132, 16133, 16134, 16135, 16136, 16137, 
16138, 16139, 16140, 16141, 16142, 16143, 16144, 16145, 16146, 
16147, 16148, 16149, 16150, 16151, 16152, 16153, 16154, 16155, 
16156, 16157, 16158, 16159, 16160, 16161, 16162, 16163, 16164, 
16165, 16166, 16167, 16168, 16169, 16170, 16171, 16172, 16173, 
16174, 16175, 16176, 16177, 16178, 16179, 16180, 16181, 16182, 
16183, 16184, 16185, 16186, 16187, 16188, 16189, 16190, 16191, 
16192, 16193, 16194, 16195, 16196, 16197, 16198, 16199, 16200, 
16201, 16202, 16203, 16204, 16205, 16206, 16207, 16208, 16209, 
16210, 16211, 16212, 16213, 16214, 16215, 16216, 16217, 16218, 
16219, 16220, 16221, 16222, 16223, 16224, 16225, 16226, 16227, 
16228, 16229, 16230, 16231, 16232, 16233, 16234, 16235, 16236, 
16237, 16238, 16239, 16240, 16241, 16242, 16243, 16244, 16245, 
16246, 16247, 16248, 16249, 16250, 16251, 16252, 16253, 16254, 
16255, 16256, 16257, 16258, 16259, 16260, 16261, 16262, 16263, 
16264, 16265, 16266, 16267, 16268, 16269, 16270, 16271, 16272, 
16273, 16274, 16275, 16276, 16277, 16278, 16279, 16280, 16281, 
16282, 16283, 16284, 16285, 16286, 16287, 16288, 16289, 16290, 
16291, 16292, 16293, 16294, 16295, 16296, 16297, 16298, 16299, 
16300, 16301, 16302, 16303, 16304, 16305, 16306, 16307, 16308, 
16309, 16310, 16311, 16312, 16313, 16314, 16315, 16316, 16317, 
16318, 16319, 16320, 16321, 16322, 16323, 16324, 16325, 16326, 
16327, 16328, 16329, 16330, 16331, 16332, 16333, 16334, 16335, 
16336, 16337, 16338, 16339, 16340, 16341, 16342, 16343, 16344, 
16345, 16346, 16347, 16348, 16349, 16350, 16351, 16352, 16353, 
16354, 16355, 16356, 16357, 16358, 16359, 16360, 16361, 16362, 
16363, 16364, 16365, 16366, 16367, 16368, 16369, 16370, 16371, 
16372, 16373, 16374, 16375, 16376, 16377, 16378, 16379, 16380, 
16381, 16382, 16383, 16384, 16385, 16386, 16387, 16388, 16389, 
16390, 16391, 16392, 16393, 16394, 16395, 16396, 16397, 16398, 
16399, 16400, 16401, 16402, 16403, 16404, 16405, 16406, 16407, 
16408, 16409, 16410, 16411, 16412, 16413, 16414, 16415, 16416, 
16417, 16418, 16419, 16420, 16421, 16422, 16423, 16424, 16425, 
16426, 16427, 16428, 16429, 16430, 16431, 16432, 16433, 16434, 
16435, 16436, 16437, 16438, 16439, 16440, 16441, 16442, 16443, 
16444, 16445, 16446, 16447, 16448, 16449, 16450, 16451, 16452, 
16453, 16454, 16455, 16456, 16457, 16458, 16459, 16460, 16461, 
16462, 16463, 16464, 16465, 16466, 16467, 16468, 16469, 16470, 
16471, 16472, 16473, 16474, 16475, 16476, 16477, 16478, 16479, 
16480, 16481, 16482, 16483, 16484, 16485, 16486, 16487, 16488, 
16489, 16490, 16491, 16492, 16493, 16494, 16495, 16496, 16497, 
16498, 16499, 16500, 16501, 16502, 16503, 16504, 16505, 16506, 
16507, 16508, 16509, 16510, 16511, 16512, 16513, 16514, 16515, 
16516, 16517, 16518, 16519, 16520, 16521, 16522, 16523, 16524, 
16525, 16526, 16527, 16528, 16529, 16530, 16531, 16532, 16533, 
16534, 16535, 16536, 16537, 16538, 16539, 16540, 16541, 16542, 
16543, 16544, 16545, 16546, 16547, 16548, 16549, 16550, 16551, 
16552, 16553, 16554, 16555, 16556, 16557, 16558, 16559, 16560, 
16561, 16562, 16563, 16564, 16565, 16566, 16567, 16568, 16569, 
16570, 16571, 16572, 16573, 16574, 16575, 16576, 16577, 16578, 
16579, 16580, 16581, 16582, 16583, 16584, 16585, 16586, 16587, 
16588, 16589, 16590, 16591, 16592, 16593, 16594, 16595, 16596, 
16597, 16598, 16599, 16600, 16601, 16602, 16603, 16604, 16605, 
16606, 16607, 16608, 16609, 16610, 16611, 16612, 16613, 16614, 
16615, 16616, 16617, 16618, 16619, 16620, 16621, 16622, 16623, 
16624, 16625, 16626, 16627, 16628, 16629, 16630, 16631, 16632, 
16633, 16634, 16635, 16636, 16637, 16638, 16639, 16640, 16641, 
16642, 16643, 16644, 16645, 16646, 16647, 16648, 16649, 16650, 
16651, 16652, 16653, 16654, 16655, 16656, 16657, 16658, 16659, 
16660, 16661, 16662, 16663, 16664, 16665, 16666, 16667, 16668, 
16669, 16670, 16671, 16672, 16673, 16674, 16675, 16676, 16677, 
16678, 16679, 16680, 16681, 16682, 16683, 16684, 16685, 16686, 
16687, 16688, 16689, 16690, 16691, 16692, 16693, 16694, 16695, 
16696, 16697, 16698, 16699, 16700, 16701, 16702, 16703, 16704, 
16705, 16706, 16707, 16708, 16709, 16710, 16711, 16712, 16713, 
16714, 16715, 16716, 16717, 16718, 16719, 16720, 16721, 16722, 
16723, 16724, 16725, 16726, 16727, 16728, 16729, 16730, 16731, 
16732, 16733, 16734, 16735, 16736, 16737, 16738, 16739, 16740, 
16741, 16742, 16743, 16744, 16745, 16746, 16747, 16748, 16749, 
16750, 16751, 16752, 16753, 16754, 16755, 16756, 16757, 16758, 
16759, 16760, 16761, 16762, 16763, 16764, 16765, 16766, 16767, 
16768, 16769, 16770, 16771, 16772, 16773, 16774, 16775, 16776, 
16777, 16778, 16779, 16780, 16781, 16782, 16783, 16784, 16785, 
16786, 16787, 16788, 16789, 16790, 16791, 16792, 16793, 16794, 
16795, 16796, 16797, 16798, 16799, 16800), class = "Date"), ts1 = c(6, 
13, 12, 7, 5, 7, 28, 73, 114, 123, 46, 77, 14, 8, 18, 7, 12, 
8, 8, 8, 16, 17, 44, 68, 29, 61, 7, 7, 10, 11, 9, 8, 12, 25, 
7, 5, 11, 7, 6, 14, 7, 8, 30, 19, 11, 9, 22, 58, 32, 55, 60, 
11, 11, 20, 7, 6, 10, 10, 8, 8, 7, 7, 8, 20, 45, 39, 36, 8, 44, 
19, 29, 23, 46, 37, 27, 41, 52, 13, 15.9067207017892, 17, 3, 
4, 21, 5, 10, 16, 16, 12, 5, 17, 12, 10, 8, 6, 12, 22, 48, 25, 
31, 20, 23, 9, 9, 20, 14, 26, 15, 7, 12, 2, 6, 8, 12, 10, 6, 
4, 3, 10, 20, 9, 8, 9, 7, 8, 21, 22, 32, 21, 20, 12, 7, 11, 7, 
9, 6, 8, 4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 6, 5, 3, 6, 6, 7, 12, 10, 7, 5, 8, 
11, 4, 6, 12, 3, 9, 5, 15, 9, 13, 10, 8, 5, 6, 7, 6, 3, 7, 3, 
6, 7, 6, 8, 8, 14, 5, 4, 7, 4, 8, 10, 11, 9, 4, 6, 12, 8, 8, 
10, 8, 6, 11, 9, 20, 24, 13, 3, 4, 9, 9, 8, 6, 12, 5, 4, 7, 8, 
6, 8, 3, 3, 4, 12, 6, 7, 7, 9, 7, 2, 8, 8, 5, 7, 5, 7, 10, 10, 
6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 5, 15, 8, 9, 18, 8, 7, 7, 11, 12, 10, 5, 14, 5, 
7, 12, 13, 12, 4, 13, 14, 6, 11, 14, 6, 7, 10, 17, 9, 16, 9, 
10, 18, 22, 13, 9, 33, 38, 15, 15, 19, 26, 8, 21, 6, 14, 10, 
15, 15, 4, 5, 9, 13, 16, 34, 39, 20, 74, 99, 30, 76, 64, 35, 
34, 51, 65, 72, 107, 55, 42, 29, 10, 9, 14, 18, 11, 7, 11, 28, 
13, 4, 22, 7, 5, 5, 13, 79, 54, 34, 44, 39, 24, 52, 75, 21, 23, 
24, 26, 45, 30, 32, 31, 32, 55, 40, 30, 53, 54, 94, 170, 111, 
19, 18, 44, 98, 144, 193, 218, 125, 85, 58, 88, 81, 30, 96, 70, 
14, 28, 69, 142, 140, 165, 146, 160, 117, 106, 155, 178, 208, 
123, 80, 86, 89, 73, 28, 13, 13, 10, 20, 45, 16, 20, 76, 57, 
23, 62, 63, 79, 28, 6, 7, 7, 7, 9, 11, 13, 19, 31, 24, 17, 18, 
24, 31, 21, 5, 7, 17, 13, 15, 26, 49, 10, 10, 9, 8, 10, 19, 22, 
20, 8, 15, 35, 56, 19, 39, 95, 48, 56, 71, 63, 53, 17, 11, 8, 
20, 18, 15, 8, 9, 9, 9, 27, 12, 10, 13, 26, 61, 11, 18, 45, 17, 
8, 10, 9, 6, 10, 9, 8, 13, 14, 17, 8, 12, 9, 15, 5, 6, 9, 5, 
5.91283674674366, 6.49649684307445, 7.08015693940525, 7.66381703573604, 
8.24747713206684, 8.83113722839763, 9.41479732472843, 9.99845742105922, 
11, 5, 20, 5, 9, 5, 16, 3, 9, 23, 4, 17, 19, 20, 15, 40, 9, 5, 
7, 11, 10, 10, 10, 9, 10, 6, 6, 10, 13, 12, 13, 10, 10, 7, 11, 
10, 12, 6, 8, 7, 8, 8, 8, 10, 11, 9, 4, 3, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 
15, 7, 13, 10, 11, 11, 21, 11, 10, 17, 14, 9, 8, 7, 6, 6, 21, 
18, 16, 13, 17, 11, 9, 10, 12, 11, 13, 9, 5, 4, 21, 16, 13, 12, 
10, 7, 7, 9, 12, 11, 12, 11, 10, 12, 13, 7, 9, 24, 14, 7, 7, 
13, 12, 8, 7, 7, 8, 5, 8, 10, 10, 14, 21, 6, 3, 6, 13, 16, 14, 
34, 9, 7, 10, 15, 11, 6, 11, 9, 9, 15, 15, 16, 13, 31, 12, 2, 
8, 7, 7, 12, 30, 24, 19, 36, 25, 15, 32, 32, 28, 13, 13, 21, 
20, 45, 11, 15, 6, 10, 8, 17, 25, 40, 35, 7, 7, 35, 29, 35, 69, 
21, 16, 21, 15, 28, 52, 89, 67, 14, 13, 8, 6, 17, 55, 22, 11, 
10, 9, 30, 31, 99, 82, 38, 56, 129, 162, 107, 101, 35, 54, 85, 
108, 139, 139, 120, 12, 9, 28, 55, 11, 65, 61, 62, 64, 161, 138, 
177, 148, 188, 120, 75, 46, 57, 67, 64, 35, 21, 48, 33, 83, 128, 
177, 146, 117, 62, 94, 113, 123, 101, 80, 48, 20, 23, 23, 17, 
28), ts2 = c(9, 26, 29, 10, 18, 15, 42, 150, 172, 199, 107, 94, 
15, 10, 23, 12, 23, 11, 9, 14, 53, 21, 80, 81, 40, 84, 6, 10, 
10, 14, 12, 7, 21, 44, 12, 8, 15, 10, 8, 16, 9, 16, 36, 22, 16, 
14, 40, 85, 65, 113, 75, 15, 19, 39, 16, 8, 11, 16, 10, 7, 7, 
6, 8, 21, 83, 71, 79, 20, 61, 35, 40, 47, 69, 64, 52, 63, 73, 
33, 45, 23, 8, 14, 43, 6, 13, 40, 21, 10, 9, 32, 19, 17, 8, 7, 
13, 43, 53, 51, 56, 52, 56, 14, 31, 43, 23, 26, 26, 22, 27, 4, 
8, 10, 20, 15, 10, 7, 7, 18, 25, 14, 11, 10, 6, 13, 34, 41, 42, 
41, 24, 26, 15, 20, 8, 7, 4, 7, 5, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 9, 9, 5, 7, 
7, 10, 19, 9, 6, 4, 11, 23, 11, 9, 24, 7, 11, 8, 21, 9, 25, 18, 
7, 4, 6, 8, 9, 5, 8, 4, 16, 11, 8, 11, 15, 29, 9, 6, 14, 6, 13, 
10, 17, 25, 7, 12, 17, 9, 10, 12, 11, 7, 28, 10, 41, 43, 35, 
4, 6, 31, 13, 20, 9, 21, 7, 5, 18, 8, 8, 20, 6, 5, 4, 19, 13, 
21, 18, 15, 11, 4, 13, 17, 8, 5, 6, 5, 11, 14, 18, 16, 10, 8, 
12, 16, 28, 20, 22, 39, 17, 11, 8, 13, 26, 22, 9, 24, 12, 19, 
21, 20, 46, 7, 32, 25, 20, 23, 26, 13, 15, 17, 46, 20, 29, 15, 
21, 23, 37, 17, 13, 56, 80, 18, 23, 53, 42, 17, 51, 12, 19, 19, 
25, 24, 8, 9, 14, 40, 22, 59, 95, 58, 117, 118, 53, 96, 143, 
69, 80, 110, 106, 122, 178, 134, 91, 45, 26, 12, 20, 26, 15, 
8, 17, 29, 25, 11, 29, 13, 10, 9, 18, 93, 82, 62, 84, 64, 34, 
127, 89, 38, 29, 34, 31, 47, 41, 70, 62, 38, 81, 67, 54, 78, 
111, 151, 214, 148, 34, 24, 59, 145, 215, 264, 268, 220, 108, 
129, 169, 115, 79, 183, 101, 11, 21, 166, 158, 155, 235, 198, 
259, 203, 141, 189, 197, 271, 163, 143, 160, 106, 122, 37, 18, 
36, 26, 20, 66, 38, 30, 142, 73, 46, 149, 113, 156, 60, 12, 9, 
6, 14, 10, 14, 11, 30, 69, 37, 21, 24, 30, 64, 70, 8, 8, 20, 
8, 11, 72, 62, 16, 20, 17, 12, 14, 23, 25, 54, 12, 14, 59, 73, 
25, 78, 115, 69, 81, 95, 102, 76, 46, 16, 10, 42, 18, 11, 5, 
7, 6, 6, 25, 8, 7, 24, 60, 97, 21, 25, 66, 15, 17, 31, 5, 10, 
13, 8, 6, 13, 21, 33, 8, 10, 14, 17, 7, 11, 40, 10, 37, 11, 6, 
33, 35, 5, 8, 7, 34, 12, 30, 5, 10, 6, 25, 3, 17, 42, 5, 31, 
33, 46, 25, 53, 12, 3, 7, 12, 11, 10, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 17, 10, 
10, 13, 13, 15, 13, 17, 10, 9, 3, 6, 8, 3, 7, 5, 7, 9, 6, 9, 
3, 6, 17, 9, 16, 10, 13, 15, 15, 10, 14, 10, 32, 18, 21, 16, 
15, 6, 5, 5, 13, 22, 25, 28, 23, 5, 16, 5, 3, 5, 6, 9, 17, 5, 
2, 3, 16, 15, 8, 9, 19, 5, 8, 15, 18, 11, 6, 8, 3, 11, 12, 3, 
18, 25, 18, 3, 3, 7, 13, 14, 4, 4, 3, 4, 6, 4, 6, 11, 14, 3, 
2, 4, 18, 22, 16, 39, 5, 3, 11, 18, 6, 4, 6, 8, 8, 10, 22, 29, 
12, 34, 20, 4, 5, 4, 5, 11, 46, 35, 34, 51, 46, 17, 41, 87, 85, 
30, 8, 24, 11, 46, 11, 30, 12, 9, 6, 41, 37, 85, 46, 15, 13, 
53, 50, 89, 134, 46, 20, 39, 21, 52, 94, 153, 132, 38, 19, 11, 
6, 30, 104, 23, 12, 13, 15, 39, 47, 132, 136, 92, 101, 163, 219, 
167, 157, 72, 84, 121, 146, 187, 174, 130, 9, 10, 38, 86, 16, 
87, 77, 77, 75, 205, 221, 196, 194, 274, 159, 129, 136, 74, 126, 
146, 90, 22, 82, 64, 134, 173, 216, 180, 151, 98, 123, 180, 190, 
127, 99, 94, 66, 37, 20, 24, 36), ts3 = c(16, 35, 36, 14, 16, 
18, 38, 67, 82, 85, 59, 81, 39, 50.323876248557, 56, 37, 30, 
24, 18, 41, 50, 42, 56, 106, 30, 82, 27, 34, 38, 31, 40, 19, 
18, 53, 30, 31, 21, 32, 17, 20, 16, 32, 45, 47, 29, 18, 23, 47, 
38, 100, 78, 19, 20, 21, 26, 28, 25, 35, 22, 17, 19, 19, 23, 
32, 48, 50, 32, 8, 27, 24, 24, 22, 47, 20, 34, 42, 55, 18, 25, 
34, 12, 10, 43, 17, 16, 35, 20, 16, 12, 26, 18, 24, 24, 23, 25, 
40, 51, 36, 38, 32, 30, 10, 11, 17, 17, 22, 8, 7, 16, 10, 17, 
27, 29, 28, 20, 17, 9, 20, 27, 17, 8, 8, 5, 8, 33, 31, 42, 20, 
17, 10, 11, 16, 11, 12, 4, 9, 7, 7, 17, 19, 17, 25, 21, 8, 10, 
12, 16, 19, 26, 14, 5, 4, 10, 18, 22, 21, 29, 16, 17, 21, 25, 
13, 15, 19, 4, 4, 7, 8, 12, 5, 10, 11, 12, 19, 14, 14, 19, 23, 
16, 5, 13, 23, 14, 26, 22, 13, 14, 21, 18, 12, 10, 10, 6, 5, 
16, 17, 32, 50, 27, 10, 6, 11, 14, 18, 13, 21, 7, 6, 11, 9, 10, 
15, 15, 7, 7, 13, 7, 9, 11, 18, 10, 6, 15, 9, 8, 5, 4, 4, 10, 
15, 11, 9, 13, 11, 9, 8, 22, 15, 19, 36, 19, 7, 8, 17, 17, 23, 
19, 29, 17, 19, 17, 25, 22, 21, 27, 19, 16, 26, 28, 21, 24, 22, 
27, 10, 21, 28, 23, 31, 29, 14, 12, 58, 69, 20, 22, 34, 23, 18, 
104, 29, 28, 31, 32, 18, 10, 26, 31, 39, 42, 69, 39, 17, 156, 
122, 36, 69, 78, 52, 43, 85, 98, 114, 144, 74, 55, 34, 26, 23, 
32, 40, 31, 17, 17, 38, 36, 33, 35, 28, 21, 21, 39, 83, 59, 46, 
49, 40, 31, 66, 93, 40, 32, 33, 36, 46, 45, 49, 40, 34, 62, 36, 
34, 78, 69.8058917794093, 74.7784041080873, 79.7509164367653, 
126, 23, 17, 60, 122, 166, 241, 279, 87, 42, 55, 95, 51, 15, 
103, 59, 11, 24, 101, 173, 180, 202, 145, 171, 159, 111, 132, 
94, 220, 122, 61, 67, 63, 77, 37, 34, 28, 17, 27, 73, 42, 40, 
93, 53, 29, 73, 60, 105, 66, 28, 13, 10, 30, 29, 18, 15, 28, 
33, 27, 22, 24, 26, 44, 42, 16, 16, 26, 14, 21, 35, 49, 11, 19, 
30, 19, 28, 32, 36, 30, 18, 36, 48, 46, 21, 64, 90, 52, 70, 49, 
71, 72, 36, 8, 6, 25, 19, 20, 8, 11, 11, 10, 34, 15, 11, 30, 
39, 50, 12, 23, 46, 13, 7, 9, 6, 7, 11, 13, 10, 16, 17, 10, 7, 
12, 15, 18, 22, 22, 19, 7, 14, 13, 15, 28, 35, 13, 9, 22, 18, 
21, 36, 11, 16, 16, 26, 17, 19, 27, 22, 28, 30, 35, 20, 51, 21, 
4, 4, 13, 15, 9, 6, 6, 7, 4, 4, 8, 8, 9, 16, 17, 8, 5, 13, 16, 
12, 4, 9, 4, 3, 6, 5, 6, 14, 14, 7, 5, 5, 5, 5, 9, 5, 10, 4, 
19, 7, 5, 8, 20, 15, 8, 13, 11, 8, 9, 9, 5, 11, 22, 29, 12, 6, 
17, 5, 3, 5, 11, 7, 5.89693402941316, 4, 3, 5, 6.9965407669608, 
8.45003150393571, 9.90352224091061, 11.3570129778855, 20, 4, 
3, 11, 11, 14, 9, 14, 2, 9, 14, 8, 11, 20, 20, 3, 3, 8, 9, 15, 
5, 5, 3, 4, 6, 4, 9, 10, 14, 3, 6, 6, 14, 23, 18, 38, 5, 4, 15, 
12, 14, 13, 9, 5, 5, 15, 20, 25, 28, 36, 17, 12, 20, 19, 19, 
20, 50, 46, 28, 33, 46, 12, 24, 33, 29, 13, 12, 16, 17, 35, 22, 
22, 12, 19, 22, 23, 32, 44, 43, 11, 11, 40, 38, 42, 96, 23, 19, 
26, 20, 36, 56, 93, 68, 18, 18, 24, 29, 37, 58, 19, 11, 14, 27, 
58.8197176941328, 80.1971121359686, 151, 59, 57, 69, 173, 190, 
144, 85, 50, 47, 96, 111, 121, 143, 152, 16, 15, 17, 96, 28, 
73, 80, 89, 50, 151, 97, 201, 131, 158, 139, 48, 32, 48, 65, 
52, 38, 21, 55, 45, 107, 103, 149, 151, 99, 44, 99, 119, 119, 
99, 86, 45, 19, 35, 38, 30, 29), ts4 = c(2, 7, 4, 2, 2, 4, 14, 
41, 55, 53, 28, 69, 5, 3, 16, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3, 9, 10, 25, 79, 7, 
57, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 15, 3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 6, 2, 3, 17, 18, 
5, 2, 8, 24, 11, 62, 52, 3, 4, 7, 3, 3, 2, 7, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
9, 18, 15, 23, 2, 12, 6, 9, 5, 26, 6, 12, 18, 34, 5, 26, 29, 
5, 5, 38, 4, 6, 21, 13, 9, 4, 14, 8, 9, 5, 4, 7, 25, 32, 13, 
17, 15, 14, 4, 6, 10, 8, 11, 5, 2, 10, 1, 5, 6, 10, 10, 2, 3, 
1, 3, 16, 9, 7, 5, 1, 6, 13, 20, 29, 11, 6, 6, 4, 6, 3, 4, 2, 
3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 3, 4, 8, 4, 2, 2, 5, 5, 3, 5, 
10, 2, 7, 4, 9, 7, 8, 9, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 5, 2, 8, 12, 6, 5, 
7, 8, 5, 2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 7, 7, 2, 2, 7, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 6, 5, 8, 
15, 13, 2, 1, 5, 5, 7, 4, 14, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 6, 3, 1, 2, 11, 
3, 4, 4, 9, 5, 2, 9, 5, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 8, 6, 4, 5, 4, 3, 3, 11, 
5, 5, 16, 6, 3, 4, 6, 6, 10, 4, 17, 4, 6, 8, 8, 8, 3, 11, 9, 
4, 10, 11, 5, 8, 8, 13, 3, 9, 13, 8, 7, 13, 8, 4, 33, 25, 8, 
9, 17, 10, 5, 24, 5, 10, 7, 13, 6, 2, 3, 6, 13, 11, 32, 18, 10, 
55, 93, 23, 42, 48, 15, 16, 31, 41, 52, 70, 37, 37, 34, 10, 7, 
8, 16, 8, 6, 7, 31, 13, 8, 16, 9, 5, 5, 10, 57, 43, 19, 25, 17, 
12, 25, 62, 14, 15, 12, 21, 28, 14, 21, 14, 11, 33, 19, 13, 40, 
30, 60, 140, 56.2272902294262, 3, 1, 22, 71, 107, 165, 223, 76, 
9, 18, 46, 30, 3, 54, 37, 1, 3, 43, 139, 128, 134, 93, 105, 116, 
80, 99, 65, 137, 84, 44, 32, 27, 42, 10, 1, 3, 2, 5, 36, 6, 6, 
51, 23, 6, 23, 23, 45, 24, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 8, 4, 3, 2, 
2, 7, 7, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 5, 12, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 6, 3, 1, 5, 
8, 20, 4, 15, 47, 25, 22, 15, 40, 42, 23, 1, 1, 4, 4, 2, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 9, 2, 1, 3, 8, 31, 1, 5, 20, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 1, 6, 8, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 11, 
1, 2, 1, 7, 1, 2, 8, 2, 1, 11, 2, 4, 11, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 6, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 
1, 6, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 5, 6, 1, 1, 1, 2, 6, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8, 4, 8, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 5, 5, 7, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 7, 22, 
1, 6, 4.85225971925742, 3.90004744507344, 2, 1, 4, 2, 17, 5, 
5, 1, 2, 1, 3, 11, 14, 23, 1, 1, 23, 11, 9, 42, 6, 3, 4, 4, 8, 
22, 37, 34, 6, 3, 2, 2, 7, 25, 4, 1, 1, 2, 10, 22, 64, 32, 16, 
24, 73, 96, 47, 37, 56.0083401831199, 61.4714231968121, 66.9345062105044, 
67, 98, 86, 109, 1, 1, 5, 49, 5, 38, 34, 59, 41, 64, 55, 184, 
81, 102, 90, 20, 18, 27, 35, 24, 14, 5, 32, 18, 58, 68, 105, 
106, 71, 20, 59, 81, 89, 81, 56, 14, 4, 8, 11, 6, 12)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -730L))
```